# Would like to know if the way I'm adding a list to another cumulative list is the most efficient way

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 2 lists (Person and PersonMeta). I'm getting data for peopleList from some Api and then adding that to personMetaList (where PersonMeta inherits from Person). I'm using AutoMapper to map the objects.

My question is about the way I'm cumulatively adding peopleList to peopleMetaList (last line of code). Is that best way/efficient way of adding list to another list?

```
class Person
{
  int id {get;set;}
  string name {get;set;}
}

class PersonMeta : Person
{
  string metaProperty1 {get;set;} 
}

List<PersonMeta> peopleMetaList = new List<PersonMeta>();

List<Person> peopleList = getFromApiSomehow();

peopleList.ForEach(x => listPeopleMeta.Add(Mapper.Map<PersonMeta>(x)));
```

Comment: Not better or worse but different `var metaList = peopleList.Select(person => Mapper.Map<PersonMeta>(person)).ToList();`

Comment: I use the following syntax to map collection of items to another collection. Mapper.Map<List<Person>,List<PersonMeta>>(peopleList).

Comment: @Thangadurai how do you then append peopleList data to peopleMetaList?

Comment: You just need to assign the returned list to peopleMetaList. `peopleMetaList = Mapper.Map<List<Person>,List<PersonMeta>>(peopleList);`

Comment: Write your own mapping between the types if you care about performance because Automapper is using reflection for mapping which is not the most efficient thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to do it, in my opinion, is to create your own custom map. Don't iterate over the collection, mapping each value. Automapper does that for you.

Please read here the documentation of how to use the ConvertUsing() function

http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html

The only thing you need to do is implement a TypeConverter and specify it on your automapper configuration